# Selecting Multiple Counts from the database

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User model and a Workplace model.
User has a field gender(m/f) and each workplace has many users.
I want to select the count of total number of users in a workplace and also the count of total number of female users of a workplace all grouped by workplace name.

Here is what I tried.

```
User.select("workplaces.name as workplace_name, count(*), count(case when users.gender='f' then 1 else 0 end) as females").joins("INNER JOIN workplaces on 
workplaces.id=users.workplace_id").group(:workplace_name).map(&:attributes)
```

The second count where I am using the condition to select the count of the female users does not seem to work. Giving the same result as the first count.

Is there anything wrong with the query?
What needs to be changed?

Thanks for the answer.

Update:

I replaced 0 with NULL and it worked.
Now I want to get the both male and female users and do calculation as
(females - males)/100, How I can achieve this in this query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `case when users.gender='f' then 1 else 0 end` will never return a `NULL` which means `COUNT` will count all instances of this expression, be they `1` or `0`.

Replace your second `COUNT` with `SUM`.

Comment: Thanks or 0 with NULL like this case when users.gender='f' then 1 else NULL :)

Comment: @rshetty: yes this would work too. You may even omit `ELSE`: `COUNT(CASE WHEN users.gender = 'F' THEN 1 END)`. Or even cast boolean to int: `SUM((users.gender = 'F')::INT)`

Comment: If I want to select the count of female users and male users and do calculation like (females - males)/100, and select that value. How can I do that ?

Comment: @rshetty: please post it as another question

Answer (score 0):

Replace second `COUNT` with `SUM` like this

```
User.select("workplaces.name as workplace_name, COUNT(*), 
SUM(case when users.gender='f' then 1 else 0 end) as females").
^^^ //Change here
joins("INNER JOIN workplaces on workplaces.id=users.workplace_id").
group(:workplace_name).map(&:attributes);
```